# How to change IP address to host name in IIS server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, dns, iis-express

I have hosted my .Net project in IIS server and now I have the IP address.I want to change it to host name and I have already tried following steps

> 1) Add the Host Name in site bindings according to my existing IP address in IIS server
>
> 2) Do changes in host file(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) according to the added host name

But I am getting following error when I navigate host name in browser

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is
>   invalid.

What is the solution for this problem ??

Comment: Are you trying with live website.. did you mapped the hostname to IP address by the help of DNS provider ?

Comment: Yes I am trying with live website so that I can't use my local host file to define my host name can you explain me the best way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you host the IIS server? On-premise domain environment or Cloud VM with public firewall IP address?

If you are hosting the web server in domain environment, then you need to create a CNAME for your web server in DNS and set binding host header for your website in IIS.

If you are just hosting the web server in cloud VM, then you should purchase a public domain from domain provider like Godaddy and map the domain name to your Virtual machine'S public firewall address. After that, you should add host name to your IIS site. Finally, you should be able to access the website. Just remember to allow port number in firewall inbound rule.